# Is it possible to use a router outlet inside a bootstrap modal?

Tags: angular, routes, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I'm confronted to a problem in Angular routing.

I have a component with a named router outlet. The routing works pretty well when I load my component in my page.

But when I use this component inside a bootstrap Modal, Angular doesn't find the route, I have the error message : "Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment..".

My question is :
Is it possible to tell Angular to search in the current NgbActiveModal if there is any router outlet?

Thanks !